# In rust why are type annotations required even if they are explicitly specified in a generic trait

Tags: rust, traits, type-inference, generic-programming

How can I make this code compile:

```rust
pub trait X<ApplyData> {
    fn apply(data: &mut ApplyData);
}

pub trait AAA<ApplyData, Functions: X<ApplyData>> {
    fn aaa(data: &mut ApplyData) {
        //...default code that may use Functions...and call X::apply()
    }
}

pub trait BBB<Data, Functions: X<Data>> {
    fn bbb(data: &mut Data) {
        AAA::<Data, Functions>::aaa(data); // I want to call the default aaa fn defined in the trait BBB
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations required: cannot resolve `_: AAA<Data, Functions>`
  --> src/lib.rs:11:9
   |
11 |         AAA::<Data, Functions>::aaa(data);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: required by `AAA::aaa`
  --> src/lib.rs:6:5
   |
6  |     fn aaa(data: &mut ApplyData);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Before rustc was complaining it could not infer type of Functions when I was only writing `AAA::aaa(data);` in `BBB` trait which I think makes sense.
Now I explicitly give the compiler `Functions` but the error I get is cryptic to me.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do here. The code doesn't make much sense. 
I strongly suspect that you need to include `self`, `&self` or `&mut self` in the method signatures. Or perhaps `data` should be `self`?

Comment: I don't want to include self. Its just a funny theoretical example. Assume I'm an extremist who doesn't want to use dot notation and keep anemic distinction between functions and data. Can you try to find a solution under these weird constraints?

Comment: Maybe what im trying is not possible im not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AAA` is a trait but, when a method is called, Rust needs to have enough information to determine which type's implementation to use. In this case it needs to know which implementation of `AAA` to use when calling `aaa`.

However, there is nothing in the signature of `BBB` to say *which* implementation of `AAA` to use.

It's very hard to know what you are trying to do, but something like this would provide the information:

```
pub trait BBB<T, Data, Functions: X<Data>> 
where
    T: AAA<Data, Functions>
{
    fn bbb(data: &mut Data) {
        T::aaa(data);
    }
}
```

This is saying that, when the concrete type of the implementor of `BBB` is known then we'll also know the concrete type of `T`, which will provide the implementation of `AAA`.

Comment: I just realized it, so I modified my question a little bit. What if I have a default method implementation in the trait. Can I still refer to it? without creating a struct

Comment: @J.M. No. Rust still needs to know which concrete type - in case that concrete type has its own implementation instead of the default.

Comment: Is there a way in Rust to explicitly say, I want to use the default implementation in the trait definition rather than any concrete implementation? Is there a way to make the default implementation "final" ?

Comment: Well I suppose then I don't need a trait anymore I can just use a regular function

Comment: @J.M. Exactly, If you know which function you want to call then call it. What's the use of traits in that situation?